# How To Detect The Name Of A Button Clicked And Set A Boolean Variable To Be Evaluated?

Tags: primefaces, actionlistener, actionevent

I have an actionListener to detect when a command button is clicked, then I intend to set a boolean variable to true and evaluate it in another method to be executed; if it's true, then **some** items are loaded; if it's false, **another** items  are loaded:

The xhtml:

```
<h:form id="myFormID" ... >
    <p:commandButton id="myButtonID" value="Some Title" action="#{myController.pressedFilter()}" actionListener="#{myController.checkClicked}" />
...
</h:form>
```

The Controller class:

```
//the boolean variable:
private boolean clicked;

public boolean isClicked() {
    return clicked;
}

public void setClicked(boolean clicked) {
    this.clicked = clicked;
}

//the actionListener to detect the button clicked:
public boolean checkClicked(ActionEvent ev) {
    String buttonClickedID = ev.getComponent().getClientId();

    if (buttonClickedID.equals("myFormID:myButtonID")) {
        setClicked(true);
    }

    return clicked;
}

//the method to retrieve the items:
public Collection<T> getItems() {
    if (isClicked()) {
        items = this.ejbFacade.findSomeItems();
    } else if (!isClicked()) {
        items = this.ejbFacade.findAnotherItems();
    } 
return items;
}

//clears all datatable filters:
public String pressedFilter() {
    clearAllFilters();
    return "/app/index";
}
```

Unfortunatelly, I don't know why it's not working as I expected.

If I click on the command button, the boolean variable is set to true; but when evaluating it, I don't know why the value is false.

Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong and help me to fix it to get that working as I described ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your bean scope?

Comment: It's properly working with @ViewScoped.

Comment: Well, this can be the problem. Because it is recreated every time the View changes (browser refresh). Try to use a @SessionScoped bean.

Comment: @RhuanKarlus: Or a `@ViewAccessScoped` from deltaspike: https://deltaspike.apache.org/documentation/jsf.html#@ViewAccessScoped

Comment: @Rhuan Karlus, you're right!! Thank you so much!! Please, post it as an answer so I can check as resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentionend in the comments. The problem is that you're using a `@ViewScoped` bean, which is recreated every time the view changes (e.g. browser refresh). Check it out: [JSF Scopes](https://deltaspike.apache.org/documentation/jsf.html#Scopes).

So, changing your bean scope to `@SessionScoped` may solve the problem.